# Fong's Causal Theories: what's to be gained by adding a monoid structure (frobenius monads)

Tags: ct.category-theory

Fong's paper [Causal Theories: A Categorical Perspective on Bayesian Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6201) talks about causal theories.  He refers to comonoid structure, copying and deleting at the top of page 42.  What is added to causal theories when we add monoid structure, and especially if the monoid and comonoid interact as a Frobenius monoid?

Comment: This would exclude some of the key models I believe. At least in sets, all models with such structure are trivial. Did you look at what are Frobenius bimonoids in the category Stoch? (This is the leading example)